# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-7

Good I have a raw and I am creating a property and this property has characteristics, that the user selects by a check box, I would like to know how to save the set of check boxes selected in my characteristics table with the property id

Controller

```
   
        $characteristics = new Characteristic;
        
        $characteristics->characteristic = $request->input('characteristic');
    
        $characteristics->save();
```

migration-properties

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('properties', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->nullable;
            $table->string('price')->nullable;
            $table->text('description')->nullable;
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('property_type_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('offer_type_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('spaces_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('departaments_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('municipalities_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('details_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('characteristics_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('images')->nullable;
            $table->float('lat')->nullable;
            $table->float('lng')->nullable;
            $table->string('address')->nullable;
            
            $table->timestamps();
            
            $table->foreign('property_type_id')->references('id')->on('property_type')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('offer_type_id')->references('id')->on('offer_type')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('spaces_id')->references('id')->on('spaces')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('departaments_id')->references('id')->on('departaments')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('municipalities_id')->references('id')->on('municipalities')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('details_id')->references('id')->on('details')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('characteristics_id')->references('id')->on('characteristics')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
    }
```

migration-characteristics

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('characteristics', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('property_id');
            $table->string('characteristic');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

sight with the chec

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="ascensor" value="ascensor" name="characteristic[]">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="ascensor">Ascensor</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="piscina" value="piscina" name="characteristic[]">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="piscina">Piscina</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="turco" value="turco" name="characteristic[]">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="turco">Turco </label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="jacuzzy" value="jacuzzy" name="characteristic[]">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="ascensor">jacuzzy</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="patio" value="patio" name="characteristic[]">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="piscina">Patio/Zona Verde</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="ucerrada" value="ucerrada" name="characteristic[]">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="turco">Unidad Cerrada </label>
                    </div>
                    
                     <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="s_basura" value="s_basura" name="characteristic[]">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="ascensor">Shut de basura</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="j_infantiles" value="j_infantiles" name="characteristic[]">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="piscina">Juegos Infantiles</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="r_transporte" value="r_transporte" name="characteristic[]">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="turco">Rutas de transporte </label>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your `$request->input('characteristic');` is an array instead of string.

You need a loop to solve this problem. One way can be:

```
$data = []

foreach ($request->input('characteristic') as $characteristic) {
   $data[] = [
      'characteristic' => $characteristic,
      'property_id' => '' // something
   ];
}

Characteristic::insert($data);
```

---

A nicer way can be using `->saveMany()` by setting `hasMany()` relationship.

```
$characteristics = [];

foreach ($request->input('characteristic') as $characteristic) {
   $characteristics = new Characteristic([
        'characteristic' => $characteristic
   ]);
}

$property->characteristics()->saveMany($characteristics);
```

Comment: I find the error

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'property_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `characteristics` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2020-06-25 14:23:46, 2020-06-25 14:23:46))

Comment: 'property_id => $properti->id
but it keeps giving me error

Answer (score 0):

I was able to save the data as follows

```
$piso_id = $properti->id;
        
            foreach ($request->input('characteristic') as $characteristic) {
               
               $charc = new Characteristic;
               
               $charc->property_id = $piso_id;
               $charc->characteristic = $characteristic;
               $charc->save();
            }
```